# catch postgres error in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I have table in postgressql with primare key (pk_user). If i insert wrong parametrs.

postgres call exception:( ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_user" )

this is ok, but i like catch this error and transform it to user interface ( this username is used)

my php script:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO user (....) VALUES (....)"
@$result=pg_query($dbconn,$sql);
if(!$result) {
 $error= pg_last_error($dbconn);
 if($error==='ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_user"')
   $outputmesage="this username is used";
....
}
else {
.....
}
```

but construction `if($error==='ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_user"')`
is wrong. I don know what write this. Function strcmp(str1,str2) is wrong too.

P.s:
I'm sorry for my bad english

Comment: My comment is a bit irrelevant, but shouldn't you first check if user name is already used and then try to insert it?
I do not like (maybe it's personal) the approach of doing something that I know it might be wrong and the see from the side-effects the cause.

Comment: dimitris mistriotis: No, this is the wrong way. Even if you check it first, you have no guarantee someone will not ask for the same username just between your check and insert (unless in a transaction - but that restricts concurrency and is needless there as just a single query suffices). Apart from the correctness of Torenaga's approach, it is also more effective, because it always needs just a single query, whereas you make two queries most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pg_result_error_field`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-result-error-field.php) but then you have to use `pg_send_query` and `pg_get_result` (instead of `pg_query` and its better alternative `pg_query_params`):

```
pg_send_query($dbconn,$sql);
$res = pg_get_result($dbconn);

# check for "UNIQUE VIOLATION"
if(pg_result_error_field($res,PGSQL_DIAG_SQLSTATE) == '23505') {
    ...
```

Another way is to use PDO, set the error handling to "ERRMODE_EXCEPTION", handle exceptions and look into the [exception's](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php) `code` property (which again should contain the SQLSTATE error code.

Answer (score 0):

before insert make select for this user name and it solve the problem.

but if you try to minimize the number of queries to db you can stay with your solution, just change the condition to sth like this:

```
if(strstr($error,"duplicate key value")) {
   $outputmesage="this username is used"; 
}
```

hope it'll be helpfull